Как получить все чаты с аккаунта телеграмм с помощью TDlib python
решил сделать небольшую программу с помощью TDlib, которая получала бы все чаты с аккаунта пользователя, а после могла получить всю информацию с этих чатов - отправленные сообщения и пользователей в чате, но я не понимаю как нужно оформить запрос и получить ответ со списком пользователей,
def get_all_chats():
    chat_list = []
    query = {
        '@type':'loadChats',
        'chat_list_': chat_list,
        'limit':100
    }
    td_send(query)
    return  chat_list

Вот код функции которая должна получать список 100 первых чатов и записывать их в массив chat_list, но она не работает и ничего не получает
